# A complete dummy in Recursion in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

Hi guys I have recently learn recursion, I have tried many return types and it seems that I have been struggling in this particular problem for the past day or two. And sadly I got no luck.

The idea is:

1. I enter a value and base
2. find its first remainder and store it in a string.
3. then divide the value by the base to get a new value
4. Repeat process until the value is 0 or 1, then return the whole string.

Code:

```
string convert(int value, int b){
    stringstream s;
    //Once the value is 0 or 1 it returns the whole result
    if(value ==0 || value ==1)
        return s.str();
    else
    {
        //I store the remainder results in the stringstream and call the function again
        s<<convert(value/b,b)<<value%b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One critical a-ha moment when dealing with recursion is that it almost never makes sense for the function the user calls to be recursive.  Using recursion usually means using a recursive helper function.

```
/* this is the helper function */
void convert(stringstream& s, int value, int b)
{
    if (value == 0) return;
    convert(s, value / b, b); /* recursive call */
    s << (char)('0' + value % b);
}

/* this is the function the user calls */
string convert(int value, int b)
{
    stringstream s;
    convert(s, value / b, b); /* calls helper, not itself */
    s << (char)('0' + value % b);
    return s.str();
}
```

Now the entry point takes care of some special cases:

- The ones digit is *always* stored, even if zero, so that numeric zero becomes `"0"` and not an empty string.
- The entry point creates a `stringstream`.
- The entry point gets and returns the `stringstream` buffer.

These are steps you don't want the recursive function performing.  Copying a string or stringstream at each recursive call is *very* wasteful.

Furthermore, a stringstream isn't really helpful here, since there's no real formatted output occurring.  So I would just do:

```
void convert(string& s, int value, int b)
{
    if (value == 0) return;
    convert(s, value / b, b); /* recursive call */
    s.append('0' + value % b);
}

/* this is the function the user calls */
string convert(int value, int b)
{
    string s;
    convert(s, value / b, b); /* calls helper, not itself */
    s.append('0' + value % b);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Quite an amazing work right there! I have been debugging like crazy wondering why it only returns a blank screen...though you have provided me an interesting insight of recursion, since I am learning it right now xD

Answer (score 0):

Add **return** statement in your `else` block to get complete string, like this:

```
else
{
    //I store the remainder results in the stringstream and call the function again
    s<<convert(value/b,b)<<value%b;
    return s.str();
}
```